# Difference between middleware and web services?

Tags: web-services, web, middleware

I am quite confused with these terms.
As far as I understand

Middleware provides the connection between devices/applications present in heterogeneous system.

Web services provides the methods through which the message can be transferred using the connection developed by middleware.

Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Someone has already asked this before, you can check this post out!
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51342001/difference-between-protocol-middleware-web-services-and-api#:~:text=Web%20services%20these%20are%20very%20similar%20to%20APIs.&text=Therefore%20web%20service%20can%20be,get%20the%20full%20application%20capabilities)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51342001/difference-between-protocol-middleware-web-services-and-api#:%7E:text=Web%20services%20these%20are%20very%20similar%20to%20APIs.&text=Therefore%20web%20service%20can%20be,get%20the%20full%20application%20capabilities))

Thanks!

Comment: I saw this question but still I am confused between these two that how they are both work together.
Do the middleware just provide a connection like the data transfer from client to middle ware and then in middleware layer there are web services which sends the message in one specific format to the server?